# A query failed due to an invalid table, column, or object name in power BI service

Tags: powerbi

My report was running normally yesterday but now the report on power bi service gives an error of **A query failed due to an invalid table, column, or object name**.

The gateway is online and doesn't seem to have any issues regarding that.
The report works fine on power bi desktop.

I could not figure out the exact issue for this error.

Could anyone please help me figure this out?[image]

This is what I Get from show details 
[image]
Not much detail here.

Comment: Did you try to refresh in pwer bi desktop?

Comment: what "show details" says?

Comment: @Aldert Yes sir it refreshes fine on Power bi desktop. But when i publish the same report I get this error.

Comment: @NickKrasnov I have updated original question with the snapshot after show details is clicked.

Comment: Please check if the m-query of the script are same in desktop & online..

Comment: @Aldert Can you please let me know how I can check that?

Comment: On the home tab (PBI desktop), press the edit queries, it will open the "backend of PBI". Select your table and press advanced editor. Download the online version and do same steps. If it is as you tell, the scripts should match. On the rigt of the editor you see the steps PBI is doing, this should check by selecting the steps where the problem is.

Comment: I solved my issue. There was an issue with a column name that caused the report to break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my question was simple. I work on the .pbix on my local machine and deploy the .pbix to the service linking live database from RDP.

The issue was column name difference in the local database and the live database.

I figured this out by comparing each tablename and columnname for all the tables in both databases.